# Removing the <hr /> border styling on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Why is it the simple things that IE manages to mess up the most?  Anyway I want to replace a normal hr line with a single image a bit like the - § - symbol (on its side).  Trying to make it look elegant :)

It appears the only way to actually get rid of the border in IE though is to set the color: css value.  Doing this will override whatever is set as background-image unfortunately and make the whole hr the parameter for color.

It's not possible to wrap it in a div or even really apply a class to it as the client that will be using the site is using a wysiwyg text editor which I don't really relish hacking to insert a div wrapped hr.

I am one step away from adding a div block wrapper with jquery, but that seems fundamentally wrong (shotgun vs walnut) - any suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://blog.neatlysliced.com/2008/03/hr-image-replacement/

```
<style type="text/css">
    hr {
       background: url(http://placekitten.com/800/100) no-repeat;
       border: 0;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
    hr {
        display : list-item;
        list-style : url(http://placekitten.com/800/100) inside;
        filter : alpha(opacity=0);
        margin-left: -10px;
        width : 0;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

See it working here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJxeF/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just insert the image directly and not use an <hr /> tag. However, I'm fairly certain you can get rid of the offending border by just changing it to be the color of your background. I mean, it's not actually gone, but at least it's hiding:

```
hr{
   border: #XXXXXX;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately IE does not consider HR borders as 'borders'.  If you set border: 1px #f0f solid; it'll add a fuschia border around the existing bevelled border.  FF + IE8 behave and actually realise that border: 0; means I don't want a border - IE 7 and less, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

IE8, fortunately does things properly.  So there is hope in 12 years.

If your background color is solid, just define the border as that color and it disappears.

Comment: Almost, IE snatches defeat from the jaws of victory by placing the border color (if set with color:) on _top_ of the background-image.  The mind boggles.  And I know, I feel like I'll be coding for IE6 'standards' until I die.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the color of the border to transparent - I think that'll work, anyway.

Otherwise you should just use the image itself and scrap the <hr /> tag.