# Hr Tag in IE - remove border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In other browsers except IE7 and lower the hr displays a border around the hr tag which I don't want it to.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
hr {
    margin: -3px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 19px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: url("img/split.png") center no-repeat;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

I've tried this solution, but it still appears to have a border around it.

It looks like this:

[image]

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: "News"?  That looks like a header, so just apply a background to the top of that, or to the bottom of the element preceding it.

Comment: I would also vote against using HR-s for this kind of solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/style_hr_tag.htm

It seems that there is no good way around this problem, only with a hack (using a surrounding div).

Comment: Some solution offered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070682/removing-the-hr-border-styling-on-ie

Answer (score 4):

To avoid these problems, you could use DIV tags instead. In order to make it accessible, put an HR inside like this:

```
<div class="ruler"><hr /></div>
```

then apply styles to it:

```
.ruler { border-top: 1px solid black; }

.ruler hr { display: none; }
```

This will hide the HR and make the DIV a "horizontal ruler".

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers have different models for the 'hr' element. That's why I use this:

```css
hr {
 height: 1px;
 color: #ccc;
 background-color: #ccc;
 border: 0;
}
```

This works across all major browsers. There is only one problem: IE7 and margins...

Answer (score 0):

Use only

```
border:0px
```

as

```
border:none
```

is not a valid rule.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp