# hr tag does not work in IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: css

I have used the `<hr>` tag in my code by giving color orange.

```
hr{
color:orange;
border-color:orange;
}
```

Its working in chrome, but not showing up in IE browsers.
  Kindly help me

Comment: Share your HTML code of the same

Comment: It is in the sharepoint environment i have used Jquery and appending <hr> to the specified elements.There is no HTMl code available

Comment: Are you sure that your JS code works as expected? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @Reto  Yes its working as expected in chrome.In IE browser i am unable to see the horizontal lines

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954077/hr-tag-in-ie-remove-border

Comment: This is not making any difference:(

Comment: Cannot replicate - http://jsfiddle.net/bd00ev6j/

Answer (score 0):

The `color` property is for text so that's not required.
Without seeing your code you can try:

```
hr {
  border: 1px 0 0 0;
  border-color: orange;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mb1qtdzb/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<hr/>` instead of `<hr>` and add `border-color:inherit;` as `<hr/>` does not inherit color property directly.
See link http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#foreground

Comment: i have added <hr/> .Even though its not reflecting

Comment: Have you published your code on a public url? Is it possible to see the HTML or can you create a jsfiddle?